# Ruby .each fails for single element

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator

I can iterate through an array just fine doing:

```
def source_names(packages)
    files = []
    packages.each do |package|
        files << (package + ".ads")
        files << (package + ".adb")
    end
    return files
end
```

But only so long as an array is passed in (or probably any collection). However this fails when only a single package is passed into this method as part of a greater script, because of what looks like the type being a string, instead of a single element in an array:

in 'source_names': undefined method 'each' for "Generics.Mathematics":String (NoMethodError)

So how do I have it not care that only a single element is passed in, where it's only recognized as a string?

*Clairification*: I know a string doesn't support array methods. My confusion is why i'm getting an array sometimes, and a string othertimes instead of a single element array.

Comment: `[packages].flatten.each...`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82, I hadn't thought of doing it that way, but watch out for `packages = [[9]]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Probably a good thing:). Seems a bit too hackish :/. Oh yeah, good point about `[[9]]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry, done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got that exception because the class [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html) has no instance method `each`:

```
String.instance_methods.include?(:each) #=> false
```

If `packages` is a string we need to operate on an array comprised of that string alone. We can use the method [Kernel#Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) to write:

```
Array(packages).each do |package|
```

`Array(packages)` will return `packages` if `packages` is an array and will return `[packages]` if `packages` is a single element, here a string.

I think it's better practice, however, to always pass an array to the method, even when the array contains a single element.

Comment: "I can iterate through an array just fine... so long as an array is passed in..." Yeah, I know why the problem is happening. Just not use to having to fight with a type system like this. Looks like this did the trick though!

Comment: It's better to use `Array(packages)`; the result matches the `[*input]` incantation, but it's more revealing of its intent and doesn't create a new array if it's already an array, reducing memory/cpu usage.

Comment: @coreyward, good suggestion, thanks. I did an edit. Readers: formerly I wrote `[*packages].each do |package|`. If `packages` is an array, `[*packages]` returns `packages`; if `packages` is a string, `[*packages]` returns `[packages]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving that error because your method expects an array, but you're passing in a string, and a string doesn't have an `each` method. The difference is `source_names(['one'])` vs `source_names('one')`, notice the first is an array containing a string, while the other is only a string. If you want to be able to pass in an unlimited number of arguments, which is what it sounds like you're wanting to do, you should use the splat `*` operator in your method:

```
def source_names(*packages)
  files = []
  packages.each do |package|
    files << (package + ".ads")
    files << (package + ".adb")
  end
  return files
end
```

Then you can call it like,

```
source_names('one')
```

or

```
source_names('one', 'two')
```

But you can no longer pass in an array unless you use the splat operator again,

```
args = ['one', 'two']
source_names(*args)
```

Comment: "I can iterate through an array just fine... so long as an array is passed in..." Yeah, I know why the problem is happening. Just not use to having to fight with a type system like this.
What's passed into source_names() is command line input, or output from another command that receives command line input.

Comment: @PatrickKelly okay—so how are you parsing the command line input? I ask because it's odd that you have an array sometimes and a string at other times. You should make sure you're parsing things consistently.