# Get ruby rails error message NoMethodError in Communities#show when i click link from home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whats i'm trying to do:
I'm new to programming in ruby.  What i was trying to do is have a list of community categories associated with post made in those communities in my drop down list as links in my application layout.  After the links pop up in my link drop down list I want to click to that community where it shows all the post associated with it.

Whats currently happening
 I've tried a few different things and search but couldn't quite find somehting of what i was trying to do even though i know it can be done.  Right now even though my links are being loaded in sub menu in my application layout.  when i click on the link or any other links i get the no method error.  Here is my code below.

Thanks for any help given.

My code snippet in application.html.erb

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown">Communities</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <% @communities.each do |lnk| %>
      <li><%= link_to lnk.name,  community_path(lnk.id) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</li>     
<li><%= link_to "Blog", root_path %></li>
```

Here is my communities controller

```
class CommunitiesController < ApplicationController
  attr_accessor :name, :id

  def index
    @communities = Community.all.order('name DESC')
    render 'posts/index'
  end

  def show
    @communities = Community.find(params[:id])
    #render 'communities/show'
  end

  private 

  def community_params
    params.require(:community).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

Here is my post controller I added my instance variable for communities there again since it kept throwing an error message

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:idex, :show]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @communities = Community.all.order('name DESC')
  end

  def new 
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    # we will first create the post
    @post = Post.new(post_params) 
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body))
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end 
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private 

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end

end
```

Here are my model

```
class Community < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :post
end
```

here my model for post

```
class Post <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

Here is my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts do 
    resources :comments
  end  
  resources :communities
  root "posts#index"
  get '/about', to: 'pages#about'
end
```

Here is my html output

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown">Communities</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/communities/6">Technology</a></li>
    <li><a href="/communities/4">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="/communities/5">Science</a></li>
    <li><a href="/communities/3">Politics</a></li>
    <li><a href="/communities/2">Local News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/communities/1">Art</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>     
<li><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
```

Comment: What is the full error you're getting? `NoMethodError` will tell you what method is missing and what the object you're calling it on is. E.g. `NoMethodError (undefined method 'join' for 6:Integer)`

Comment: its says 
NoMethodError in Communities#show
undefined method `each' for #<Community:0x00007f437885f378>

Answer (score 2):

This is your issue:

```
@communities = Community.find(params[:id])
```

And here's why:

```
<% @communities.each do |lnk| %>
  <li><%= link_to lnk.name,  community_path(lnk.id) %></li>
<% end %>
```

`find` returns a single record (an instance of `Community`), not a collection. `each` iterates over a collection.

You probably want something like this:

```
@community = Community.find(params[:id])
@communities = Community.all
```

Comment: Nice one @coreyward. Will, here is an answer elsewhere on stack-overflow for how to give each a collection if you sometimes it will be a single element and other times it will be a collection.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44480057

Comment: @MichaelDimmitt The return value of `find` is never a collection, and `@communities` (plural) should always be a collection.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the instance and made it an array.

```
<% [*@communities].each do |lnk| %>
      <li><%= link_to lnk.name,  community_path(lnk.id) %></li>
 <% end %>
```